# position tables neatly

Tags: tables, captions, positioning, labels, subcaption

I am currently trying to place these tables neatly, but seem to have problem doing so..

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action  \\ 
\hline A & 4 & D  \\ 
\hline Eight & 2 & D  \\ 
\hline B & 1 & D \\ 
\hline C & 1 & D \\ 
\hline Eighty & 1 & D \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action  \\ 
\hline A & 4 & I  \\ 
\hline E & 3 & I  \\ 
\hline O & 3 & I \\ 
\hline Eight & 1 & I \\ 
\hline GO & 1 & I \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action & Output \\ 
\hline OH & 6 & S & O \\ 
\hline A & 5 & S & K\\ 
\hline D & 4 & S & T\\ 
\hline L & 4 & S & O\\ 
\hline M & 4 & S & N\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

How do position first two tables next to each other, and third one at the center under the first two..

So something like this:

[image]

Edit: 
Could subcaption and and a overall captioned be added to the tables, such that they can be crossreferenced individually, and reference them all serperately..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your tables are quit wide, so I use `geometry package to make smaller margins on page. And note: empty line between table means that you require that next table should go to the next line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action  \\
\hline A & 4 & D  \\
\hline Eight & 2 & D  \\
\hline B & 1 & D \\
\hline C & 1 & D \\
\hline Eighty & 1 & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action  \\
\hline A & 4 & I  \\
\hline E & 3 & I  \\
\hline O & 3 & I \\
\hline Eight & 1 & I \\
\hline GO & 1 & I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline Word & No. times Action occured & Action & Output \\
\hline OH & 6 & S & O \\
\hline A & 5 & S & K\\
\hline D & 4 & S & T\\
\hline L & 4 & S & O\\
\hline M & 4 & S & N\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

You should consider that second column in table make narrower (if this allowed) by broken of column header into two lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{my tables}
    \label{tab:table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} & \thead{Action}  \\
\hline A & 4 & D  \\
\hline Eight & 2 & D  \\
\hline B & 1 & D \\
\hline C & 1 & D \\
\hline Eighty & 1 & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfil
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} & \thead{Action}  \\
\hline A & 4 & I  \\
\hline E & 3 & I  \\
\hline O & 3 & I \\
\hline Eight & 1 & I \\
\hline GO & 1 & I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} 
    & \thead{Action}    & \thead{Output}  \\
\hline OH & 6 & S & O \\
\hline A & 5 & S & K\\
\hline D & 4 & S & T\\
\hline L & 4 & S & O\\
\hline M & 4 & S & N\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
considering your last comment and use `subfig` package. Similarly you can obtain with `subcaption` package, however it require to define table width in advance ... :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{my tables}
    \label{tab:table}
\subfloat[ table 1]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} & \thead{Action}  \\
\hline A & 4 & D  \\
\hline Eight & 2 & D  \\
\hline B & 1 & D \\
\hline C & 1 & D \\
\hline Eighty & 1 & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\hfil
\subfloat[ table 2]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} & \thead{Action}  \\
\hline A & 4 & I  \\
\hline E & 3 & I  \\
\hline O & 3 & I \\
\hline Eight & 1 & I \\
\hline GO & 1 & I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\subfloat[ table 3]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \thead[b]{Word} & \thead{No. times\\ Action occurred} 
    & \thead{Action}    & \thead{Output}  \\
\hline OH & 6 & S & O \\
\hline A & 5 & S & K\\
\hline D & 4 & S & T\\
\hline L & 4 & S & O\\
\hline M & 4 & S & N\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I will try it out, would adding caption interfere with the setup or?

Comment: @dfh, i will add caption ...

Comment: I suck at this.. what about subcaptions.. Sorry for making all the chages..

Comment: well, you should make your question more clear on very beginning ... :)

Comment: Added it in the question..